# WPF Application level ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm new to WPF and MVVM, but I'm trying to create an application-level viewmodel for the multiple windows in my application.  Here's my code:

**ApplicationViewModel.cs:**

```
public class ApplicationViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
   // for MainWindow
   private MainWindowViewModel mainWindowViewModel;
   public MainWindowViewModel MainWindowViewModel
   {
      get { return this.mainWindowViewModel; }
      private set
      {
         this.mainWindowViewModel = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("MainWindowViewModel");
      }
   }

   // other window code...

   public ApplicationViewModel()
   {
      this.mainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();

      // Now show the MainWindow
      MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
      mainWindow.Show();
   }
}
```

**App.xaml:**

```
<Application x:Class="SomeApp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:SomeApp.viewModel">
   <Application.Resources>
      <viewModel:ApplicationViewModel x:Key="applicationViewModel" />
...
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="SomeApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:SomeApp.viewModel">
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource applicationViewModel}">
   <TextBox Name="courseNameTxtBox" Width="200" MaxLength="251"
            Text="{Binding Path=MainWindowViewModel.SomeMainWindowObject,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
...
```

For some reason, it seems that applicationViewModel is never instantiated as the MainWindow is never displayed.  What am I doing wrong?

I have also tried this:

**App.xaml:**

```
<Application x:Class="CourseAttendanceTracking.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Startup="Application_Startup">
...
```

**App.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
   private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
   {
      this.Resources.Add("applicationViewModel", new ApplicationViewModel());
   }
}
```

And I get this error:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred   Message='Provide
>   value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.'
>   Line number '15' and line position '19'.
>   Source=PresentationFramework   LineNumber=15   LinePosition=19
>   StackTrace:    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e,
>   IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader,
>   IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean
>   skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings
>   settings, Uri baseUri)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader,
>   Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel
>   accessLevel, Uri baseUri)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext
>   parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri
>   resourceLocator)    at SomeApp.MainWindow.InitializeComponent() in
>   \MainWindow.xaml:line 1    at SomeApp.MainWindow..ctor() in
>   \MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 25    InnerException:     Message=Cannot find
>   resource named 'applicationViewModel'. Resource names are case
>   sensitive.    Source=PresentationFramework    StackTrace:
>           at  System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension.ProvideValueInternal(IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider, Boolean allowDeferredReference)
>           at System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider)
>           at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CallProvideValue(MarkupExtension
>   me, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)    InnerException:

My XAML works fine if I do this though:

```
MainWindow.xaml
<Window.Resources>
   <viewModel:ApplicationViewModel x:Key="applicationViewModel" />
```

But I really don't want to instantiate the ApplicationViewModel in this Window as I won't be able to see it in another window.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: For starters, if you want to do MVVM right, you really shouldn't instantiate your view in your view model.

Comment: @AdiLester I actually do so.. and don't consider myself a starter. what is the right instantiation scheme in pure MVVM? I don't care about testing and do not use IoC.

Comment: The ApplicationViewModel created the MainWindow for testing purposes.  Normally I create it in App.xaml with <Application StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">, but this made it easier to debug--window pops up, constructor was called; window doesn't pop up, constructor not called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the `{StaticResource XXX}` for a `{DynamicResource XXX}`

Comment: I'll be damn, it worked (using the Application_Startup method).  Thanks!  Any idea why creating the ViewModel in <Application.Resources> didn't work?